# Migrate from Jboss EAP 6.4 to WildFly 21

Tags: java, server, jboss, migration, wildfly

In the project, we are looking to migrate the application from Jboss EAP 6.4 to Wildfly 21?
Can anyone suggest:

1. what are the factors we need to take into consideration?
2. How I can do that?
3. what changes I required to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at https://github.com/windup as it will analyse all the required changes